# AVAudioPlayer doesn't play audio after the home button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm new in ios development.I'm using AVAudioPlayer.The audio plays in foreground. After that when i tapped the home button the app comes to background but the audio was muted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = 0;
task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include that in your code at the place where you start playing the audio

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```